# String splitting and wrapping

Tags: java, c++, split

Suppose I am given this string-

```
String A_Old[]="010.011.100.000.111";
```

On every occurrence of **"000"** I am expected to **break the string and wrap the end towards the front of the string**. The resultant should look like this-

```
String A_New[]="111.010.011.100";
```

Any help on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.
Also, what do I do when there are **multiple occurrences of "000"**?

```
String A_Old[]="010.011.100.000.111.001.011.000.101.110";
```

should convert to :

```
String A_New[]="101.110.111.001.011.010.011.100";
```

Code in java or c++ is understood and appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

This was what I thought would work-

```
String b[]=A_Old.split(".000.",2);    //should split the string in 2 parts.
A_New=b[1].concat(b[0]);              // concatenation with a loss of a period
```

I was told to avoid the loss of the period as well as not using dummy variables. Both of which fails here. Any idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: I have no idea how to go about solving this. I was told not to use dummy variables.Moreover, the periods are causing me a lot of trouble.

Comment: For Java (below 8), you're going to want to use some combination of the `split` method of `String`, the `asList` method of `Arrays`, the `reverse` method of `Collections`, the `toArray` method of `Collection` and the `join` method of Apache commons `StringUtils`, in that order.  I recommend researching the Javadocs of each of these separately.

Comment: An answer has been accepted that doesn't provide a recursive solution, or even a solution devoid of intermediate variables.  Has that requirement now been relaxed?  There has been an updated Perl solution which provides both, leaving translation to other powerful languages such as Java an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: Thanks @DavidO but as you rightly said, I've relaxed the recursive solution part. You wouldn't want to deprive me of the opportunity to learn by myself would you ? :) have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate the list, you wanna split and then concatenate in the order you want.  You probably want to check for blanks/if it's the last element.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inString = "010.011.100.000.111";
    String outString = "";
    String[] arr = inString.split("\\.000\\.");
    outString = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      outString = outString + arr[i];
    }

    System.out.println(outString);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why you used " split("\\.000\\.") "

Comment: Java interprets the Split string as RegEx which considers the . character as matching ANY single character.  To match only a literal . you have to escape it hence \.  But in Java strings \ is an escape character so you have to escape it hence \\.

Answer (score 0):

"No dummy variables" sounds like a recursive solution is sought.  Is this a Scheme class?

Here's a Perl solution. C++11 is sufficiently high-level to provide most of the facilities demonstrated here:

```
my @tests = (
    '010.011.100.000.111',
    '010.011.100.000.111.001.011.000.101.110'
);

foreach ( @tests ) {
  print "$_ => ", rotate($_), "\n";  # Call our rotate routine, and show results.
}

sub rotate {
  # Split the string into components, reverse their order, join them with '.'
  return join('.', reverse split /(?:^|\.)000(?:\.|$)/, shift);
}
```

No dummy variables.  In fact, no explicit variables either.

Here's how the split regex works:

```
(?:^|\.) # Match either start of string, or a dot.
000      # Match three zeros.
(?:\.|$) # Match either a dot, or the end of string.
```

This permits the `000` to appear anywhere in the string (including beginning or end).  If it appears at the beginning, there will not need to be a leading dot.  If it appears at the end, a trailing dot will not be required.  Anywhere else, dots must surround the `000`.

**Update:**
Here is a recursive solution using Perl.  From what I've read of the Java solutions (I'm not a Java guy), it seems like translation should be straightforward for someone with some Java background.

```
my @tests = (
    '010.011.100.000.111',
    '010.011.100.000.111.001.011.000.101.110'
);

foreach ( @tests ) {
  print "($_)  =>  (", rotate($_), ")\n";
}

sub rotate {
  my( $ok, $rest ) = split /(?:^|\.)000(?:\.|$)/, $_[0], 2;
  return $ok unless defined $rest;
  return join( '.', rotate($rest), $ok);
}
```

**Update2:**
And here's another Perl solution that eliminates any explicit variables, using only subroutine parameters:

```
my @tests = (
    '010.011.100.000.111',
    '010.011.100.000.111.001.011.000.101.110'
);

foreach ( @tests ) {
  print "($_)  =>  (", rotate($_), ")\n";
}

sub rotate {
  return sub {
    return $_[0] unless defined $_[1];
    return join( '.', rotate($_[1]), $_[0]);
  }->( split /(?:^|\.)000(?:\.|$)/, shift, 2 );
}
```

I have no idea how one would translate that Java. I suspect translation would become a little more difficult, though I'm confident there must exist a semantically equivalent C++11 solution.

Comment: Thank you, I found this helpful to understand the split regex workings.However, I am not familiar with PERL so, I am unsure whether it works the same way in java.

Comment: At least I know it proved helpful at some level, though aside from the Java or C++ requirement, it does provide a recursive solution that uses no intermediate variables, and that works even if '000' appears at the beginning or end of the string.  If I ever find another 30 minutes I may translate the final solution to C++11 just for fun.  Don't hold your breath though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

By Using Split method and reverse forloop in java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //insert code here

     String A_Old="010.011.100.000.111.001.011.000.101.110";
     String A_new ="";
     String newe[]=A_Old.split("\\.000");

     for(int i=newe.length-1;i>=0;i--){
         A_new+=newe[i];

     }
     System.out.print(A_new.replaceFirst("\\.", ""));
 }
```

Comment: Still needs to make the 'dot' character optional in the '`.000.`' sequence, in case it appears at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Yes, and in fact, (I could be wrong but...) Java's split takes a regex, so the dot is going to be treated as a metacharacter that matches anything, not as a literal dot.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've tried to imitate.However, is there a recursive function that I could probably use?

Comment: @DavidO Well, I wasn't going to request for a recursive solution.I was looking forward to solve that part myself.Can you please cut the hostility? I have learnt where I was going wrong before,apparently there is something about the regex int I missed before

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in java:

```
public static String convert(String in) {
    String[] strs = in.split("\\.*000\\.*");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = strs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        sb.append(strs[i]);
        if (i > 0 && strs[i - 1].length() > 0) {
            sb.append(".");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convert("010.011.100.000.111"));
    System.out.println(convert("010.011.100.000.111.001.011.000.101.110"));
    System.out.println(convert("010.011.100.111"));
    System.out.println(convert("000.010.011.100.111"));
    System.out.println(convert("010.011.100.111.000"));
    System.out.println(convert("000.010.011.100.111.000"));
}
```

Output:

```
111.010.011.100
101.110.111.001.011.010.011.100
010.011.100.111
010.011.100.111
010.011.100.111
010.011.100.111
```

Comment: This was helpful. Could you please explain why you did this?
split("\\.*000\\.*");

Comment: It's a regexp, which `\\.*` means `.` can appear zero or one time, so it can split string by `000` or `000.` or `.000` or `.000.`.